# X Y Co-ordinates of Stacked Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I need some help in getting the X and Y Co-ordinates of a stacked bar chart for each rect in the stacked bar chart.

I'm here creating a new rectangle on hover. I want the to be created on right side top of the hovered rectangle of the stacked bar chart.

Here's the mouse over function I've defined, problem is it's giving the y value of only the first rect of a stacked bar.

```
function movein() {
    var allRect = d3.selectAll("rect")
                    // .transition()
                    // .duration(300)
                    .attr("opacity", 0)
                    .attr("display", "none")

    d3.select(this)
      .attr("opacity", 1)
      .attr("display", "block")


      d3.select('.g')
      .append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("x", 100)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr("width", 0)
      .attr("z-index", 1000)
      .attr("class", "rect-sec")

      d3.select('.rect-sec')
        .transition()
        .duration(300)
        .attr("width", 200)
  };
```

Someone please help in getting X and Y co-ordinates of each rectangle of a stacked bar on hover.

This is the [**link**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) where i'm refering for the stacked bar chart.

Comment: You haven't defined an `.on("mouseover"` function, but inside that you get access to the current element using `d3.select(this)`.

Comment: Above is the `mouseover` function where I call it like this `.on("mouseover", movein)`. You want the entire code?

Comment: Ok, so you would do `d3.select(this).attr("x")` to get the x coordinate of the currently selected `rect`.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Thanks a lot. Please make that as answer.

Comment: And can you let me know to align the text to the middle in stacked bar?

Comment: Add the text in the center and set `.attr("text-anchor", "middle")`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42483/discussion-between-user2549787-and-lars-kotthoff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select `this` inside the handler to get access to the current element, i.e. you would do

```
var x = d3.select(this).attr("x");
```

to get access to the x coordinate.

Comment: Can you let me know how will i be able to get y co-ordinate of a selective bar? Suppose 2nd or 3rd bars y co-ordinate.

Comment: You would need to identify that bar (e.g. by its data) and then get the coordinate in a similar fashion.

Comment: If I assign a class it's applicable to the whole bars. And by using data how will I be able to do it. In my case data is dynamic and it'll be changing often. Can you let know how will I identify a bar with it's data?

Comment: You have some attribute of the data of the bar you want and iterate over all bars, checking the attribute.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. I don't get what you say. Can you send me a link with some working code so that I can get hold to it?

Comment: It all depends on how you want to identify the bar. Could you post a complete working example that demonstrates what you want to do?

Comment: Here's the [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402130/d3-x-y-co-ordinates-of-select-bars-in-a-stack-graph). Please help.