# X & Y Co-ordinates of selective bars in a stack graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart. And I'd like a draw a line like grouping few bars of a stacked bar chart.

Something like this.[image]

So to do this I need to find the `y` coordinate of the 2nd and the last bar.

Some one please help in drawing those line using d3.

**JS:**

```
var width = 750,
      height = 500;

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(["#D70B16", "#154CEF", "#1A8A55"]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

  var tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function(d) {
            return "Value: " + (d.y1 - d.y0) + "";
            })

  var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 30 + "," + 30 + ")");


  d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "circle"; }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      var y0 = 0;
      d.hours = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });

      d3.select('body').append('pre')
              .text(JSON.stringify(d.hours, null, '  '));


      d.total = d.hours[d.hours.length - 1].y1;
    });

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.circle;}));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.total;})])

    svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

    svgContainer.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Login Hours");

    var circle = svgContainer.selectAll(".circle")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "g")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.circle) + ",0)"; });

    circle.selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) { return d.hours; })
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
          .on("mouseover", tip.show)
          .on("mouseout", tip.hide)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });


    circle.selectAll("text")
          .data(function(d) { return d.hours; })
          .enter()
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", 75)
          .attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(d.y1) ; })
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("test")

  })
```

Comment: Do those bars correspond to the 2nd and last data items? If so, you can do `bars.data(secondItem).attr("y")` etc.

Comment: We need to use like firstItem, secondItem and so on huh?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends how exactly you want to identify those bars. Could you post a complete working example please?

Comment: Looks like you should be able to get the coordinate directly from the data item -- `y(d.y1)`.

Comment: How do i need to do it for those selective bars? Running `y(d.y1)` will run through all the data in the array. But here i need to take the `second bar` and `third bar`. How will i do it?

Comment: You take the data items that are represented by those bars.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Can you help me with some code?

Comment: E.g. `data[0].hours[1].y1` for the y coordinate of the second bar in the first column.

Comment: I got the `y` co-ordinate of a bar. But can you please say me what is it doing.

Comment: It's a simple statement that indexes into a nested array. If you don't understand it, I would strongly suggest having a look at a few Javascript tutorials.

Comment: I'm asking about `data[0]` this thing. I do know that it's indexing through a array. But `data[0]`, i don't know what's it doing.

Comment: It's getting the first element of the array `data`.

Comment: Thank you that's the only thing was annoying. Please post it as a answer. I'll accept it. Thanks you very much again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you determine those values (and the bars) depends on how you can identify them. In this particular case, you don't actually need to get the `rect` items because the underlying data gives you access to everything you need.

To, for example, get the `y` coordinate of the second bar in the first column, you can use the following code:

```
var yCoord = y(data[0].hours[1].y1);
```

Comment: I stuck in another place. I managed to draw a line using the `code` you gave me. I drew a line from 2nd bar's `y` value to last bar's `y` value. But the line extended only till the start of the last bar. But i want that to be extended to the entire height of the last bar. Please let me know.

Comment: Got it. Tried using `y(0)` and it extended till the bottom of the bar.